# Can i Transfer Data from one raspberry pi to another over i2c?

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3b+, i2c, data-transfer

**Hi, i have following Problem:** I have A raspberry Pi 3B+ with a Touchscreen, which uses **every** Single Pin on the 40Pin GPIO header. The only thing i have is a i2c breakout on my Touchscreen. But i have the problem, that i want to control Adressable RGB strips(ws2812) over this Touchscreen and these Strips are only able to get Data directly over one of the direct GPIO on the 40Pin GPIO header.

**So i have following idea:** I add some i2c IO-Expanders for both of my raspberrys. From one Raspberry i write 8 Pins either high or low, so this 8 Outputs act as 8 bits, where is my data of brightness or color, etc. I connect these 8 outputs to the other i2c IO-Expander of my other raspberry. On this other raspberry, i read the value of the 8 bits, put them together and send this value to my LED-Strip.

So my question: I know, that its probably possible, but how fast can i transfer this data? I dont want to see any delay between input on my touchscreen and output of brightness, etc. on my LED. I know there are other ways, but i checked them and my actual idea seems best for my project. so, have yu any advice?

Comment: Which touchscreen are you using? Update your original post rather than re-posting.

Comment: I am using the Hiperpixel4 Display. They have written on ther website, that the Touchscreen is using every GPIO.